# Terraform - Update a newly create default route table for a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How can I update the default route table that is automatically created when I create a VPC by using Terraform?

I would like to add some tags to it.

This is how I create my VPC

```
module "aws_vpc" {
  source = "../../modules/Virtual Private Cloud"
  vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
  vpc_instance_tenancy = "default"
  vpc_tags = {
    Name = "Web Application VPC"
    project = "Alpha"
    cost_center = "92736"
    developer = "J.Pean"
  }
}
```

Module looks like this:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "new" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr
  instance_tenancy = "default"
  tags = var.vpc_tags
}
```

Comment: You are using a local module, so it really depends on how the local module is defined. Look at  variables.tf under "Virtual Private Cloud" for clues how to modify/create the routables.

Comment: Can't you just create your own route_table and set the vpc's main route table to that one via https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/main_route_table_association ?

Comment: @luk2302 yes I can. But it is a best practice to let a route table all alone there? :-)

Comment: Best practice? Probably not. Okay practice? Yes.

Comment: @Bob if you dont want to create a separate `route_table` as recommended by @luk2302 , you can use [null_resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource) do the necesary things on the resource as you want but then you have to fall back to CLI Commands or even a python script.

Comment: Okay practice is not what I am looking for when managing critical infrastructure. @luk2302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage your newly created route table as well as nacl and sg through the resources:

- aws_default_network_acl
- aws_default_route_table
- aws_default_security_group

[Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/default_network_acl)

Answer (score 1):

```
resource "null_resource" "tag_default_route_table" {
  triggers = {
    route_table_id = aws_vpc.new.default_route_table_id
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
      interpreter=["/bin/bash", "-c"]
      command = <<EOF
      set -euo pipefail
      aws ec2 create-tags --resources route_table_id --tags 'Key="somekey",Value=test'
      EOF
  }
}
```

Using [null_resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource)